# Olbers' Paradox in an Euclidean universe with randomly located stars

Tags: probability, geometry, physics

This question is inspired by [Olbers' Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olbers%27_paradox).

Imagine a universe $U$ shaped like $R^3$ with points $P$ randomly distributed in a Poisson fashion throughout, with density parameter $\lambda$ such that in any measurable set $S$ of volume $V$, the expected number of points in $S$ is $V$.

By "Poisson" I mean that (h/t @Rahul) for an observer who knows $\lambda$, given two disjoint measurable sets $S_1$ and $S_2$ in $U$, the distribution of the number of points in $S_1$ is independent of the distribution of the number of points in $S_2$.

My questions are:

1. Can one even speak of such a distribution rigorously? (I believe so based on [this discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143200/determining-the-distance-of-poisson-distributed-stars-in-mathbbr3))
2. Assuming such a distribution exists, if I choose an arbitrary line $L$ in $U$, must $L$ intersect at least one star?
3. (If the answer to #2 is "no") Choose a random line $L$ than intersects the origin. What is the probability that $L$ intersects at least one star?

Comment: Consider two disjoint measurable sets $S_1$ and $S_2$. Is the distribution of the number of points in $S_1$ independent of the distribution of the number of points in $S_2$? If so, then $P$ is a Poisson process and the question becomes easy. If not, then I don't know.

Comment: @Rahul, I have updated the question to state that the distribution of the points is indeed Poisson.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that given an arbitrary ray (half a line), there is a probability of 1 that that ray will intersect a star, simply because the volume of the radius $r$ cylinder around the ray is infinite, so by the property of your distribution (which I'm also persuaded exists) you can say that there is an expected infinity of stars along it somewhere.

However, this only tells us that there are almost surely stars along any ray. It doesn't actually guarantee that there will be such a star. This is like saying "If you pick a point on a dartboard, the probability of a dart arriving at exactly that point is 0, but there's nothing stopping that outcome from occuring." For a broader discussion, read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely

Comment: I think this argument is misleading! Because the same argument would be made saying that any chosen point in the unit length jnterval intersects a rational number because any interval around it has infinite number of rational numbers! Actually in that case we know that random points will NOT be rational numbers! But maybe I misunderstood your answer?

Comment: A star has a positive radius, or at least it contains some sphere that has such a radius (stars being somewhat oblate I don't want to get into whether they have a radius), and I believe that ordinary stars (non neutron/black hole type stars) have a minimum radius. Rational points do not. The ray does not need to pass through the centre of a star for a star to lie along it, it needs only to pass through the star. If we are approximating stars as points, then yes, I think the probability is 0, but stars are not points.

Comment: Just for clarity: if stars have positive radius, all lines intersect stars infinitely often with probability 1. If stars are points (which may well be the intent of the asker) the probability is 0.